# Unresolved reference: grgit in build.gradle.kts

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

Getting error like below,  When I am compiling the code using using this command "bash ./gradlew build"

Unresolved reference: grgit

build.gradle.kts :

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.FixCrLfFilter
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date

plugins {
   java
   kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.60"
   `maven-publish`
   id("com.github.xxxxx") version "5.2.0"
   id("org.ajoberstar.grgit") version "4.0.2"

 }  
val vertx = "3.8.5"
dependencies {
implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.13.0")
implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.13.0")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.2")
implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
implementation("io.vertx:vertx-core:${vertx}")
implementation("io.vertx:vertx-rx-java2:${vertx}")
implementation("io.vertx:vertx-web:${vertx}")
implementation("io.reactiverse:elasticsearch-client-rxjava2:0.8.2-ec7.6.2")
implementation("org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.25")
implementation("io.vertx:vertx-mysql-client:${vertx}")
implementation("io.vertx:vertx-shell:${vertx}")
testImplementation("junit", "junit", "4.12")
testImplementation("io.vertx", "vertx-unit", vertx)
runtimeOnly("io.vertx:vertx-hazelcast:${vertx}")
}
val gitStatus = grgit.status()
val versionTimestamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm").format(Date())
val versionCommit = grgit.head().Id
var currentBranchName = grgit.branch.current().getName();
if (currentBranchName.equals("HEAD", true)) { /* happens on jenkins */
   val usedRemoteBranch = grgit.branch.current()
```

getting error like below

Script compilation errors:

Line 69: val gitStatus = grgit.status()
^ Unresolved reference: grgit

Line 71: val versionCommit = grgit.head().Id
^ Unresolved reference: grgit

Line 72: var currentBranchName = grgit.branch.current().getName();
^ Unresolved reference: grgit

Line 74:     val usedRemoteBranch = grgit.branch.current()
^ Unresolved reference: grgit

in build.gradle.kts.

Can you please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you using this plugin: https://github.com/ajoberstar/grgit ?

Comment: yes,in plugin  id("org.ajoberstar.grgit") version "4.0.2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not declared your `grgit` variable.

You can get a `Grgit` instance by:

```
import org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit
...
val grgit = Grgit.open(mapOf("currentDir" to project.rootDir))
```

Reference: http://ajoberstar.org/grgit/index.html

Comment: thanks for your reply. But now getting FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/asas/build.gradle.kts' line: 70

* What went wrong:
No .git directory found!

Comment: Isn't git initialized in your repository?

Comment: I have initialised git , but getting exception now * What went wrong:
grgit.head() must not be null

Comment: Issue is resolved. Previously have downloaded code from google drive not form git.